# How to remove double qoutes in Objective-C

Tags: nsstring

Let me introduce myself.
My name is Vladimir, C++ programmer, I am from Serbia. two weeks ago I have started to learn objective-C and it was fine until tonight.

Problem:

I cant remove double quotes from my NSLog output.
NSLog(@"The best singers:%@", list.best);
Strings are joined with componentsJoinedByString:@" and "

I would like to get something like this:
The best singers: Mickey and John.

But I get this:
The best singers: ("Mickey", and "John").
I cant remove comma (,) and parentheses either.
I have tried with "replaceOccurencesOfString" but with no success. It can remove any character except qoute and comma.

Also I have used -(NSString *)description method to return string.

Comment: Please share your code , so that we can verify what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the raw output from your `list` (which I assume is an array). You will have to do your own formatting to get this to display in the format that you want. You can achieve this by building your string by iterating through your array. Note that this probably isn't the most efficient nor the most robust way to achieve this.

```
NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString string];
BOOL first = YES;
for (NSString *nameString in list) {
    if (first) {
        [finalString appendString:nameString];
        first = NO;
    } else {
        [finalString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" and %@", nameString]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to form output with [fisrstString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" and %@", secondString]]; but it gave same result. But when I try [firstString appendingString:secondString] then it works but than I dont have " and ".

Comment: If you know that you will always have just the two strings, then you can do `[firstString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" and %@", secondString]]`. There are a ton of different ways to handle string formatting, and it can get as complex and flexible as you want it to be. EDIT: Take a look at Apple's documentation on string formatting for more information https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH